# Which event should be fired so that when a radio button is checked something happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, radio-button

I want to hide the validation message when one of the radio button is checked.

I tried using the events click, change, and on("change", function (){...})

Version of JQuery is 1.10.2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radioButton1").on("change", function () {
        var isChecked = $("#radioButton1").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked)
            $("#validationMsg").text("");
        else
            $("#validationMsg").text("Please select something from above").css("color", "red");
    });

    $("#radioButton2").change(function () {
        var isChecked = $("#radioButton2").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked)
            $("#validationMsg").text("");
        else
            $("#validationMsg").text("Please select something from above").css("color", "red");
    });
});
```

Comment: What is not working? `change` is a  valid event handler -- you can see this from this trivial example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZNNaje

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click change', '#radioButton1, #radioButton2')` and use `$(this).is()` instead of `$('#radioButton1').is()`. Also note that your radio buttons will change both at same time, so it's possible you just get two calls instead of one

Comment: @VaughanHilts The events are not firing. I added a breakpoints on 2nd and 9th line but it doesn't break there.

Comment: The problem is probably not with that code. More info needed. I provided an example that shows the `change` handler does fire fine.

Comment: Can you please share your code on Fiddle?

Comment: @VaughanHilts You are right, there was an inline script containing a change event on the same radio buttons in the cshtml which was overriding the above code in an external js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine and should work. I would say that problem is somewhere else so It would be good if you would attach your html as well, maybe something is wrong there.

You can check that it works on my codepen:

https://codepen.io/MaimunoDampalo/pen/WBBdaZ

```
<div>
  <label>foo?
    <input name="foobar" type="radio" value="foo" id="radioButton1"/>
  </label>
  <label>bar?
    <input name="foobar" type="radio" value="bar" id="radioButton2" />
  </label>
</div>

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radioButton1").on('change', function () {
        var isChecked = $("#radioButton1").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked) {
          alert("button1 true")
        }
    });
    $("#radioButton2").on("change", function () {
        var isChecked = $("#radioButton2").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked) {
          alert("button2 true")
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Right, the problem is somewhere else.There was an inline script containing a change event on the same radio buttons in the cshtml which was overriding the above code in an external js file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of your code slightly modified.

The change event is triggered on both radio buttons, and the value is logged to the console. The message will clear itself if either option is selected. It's not clear whether you're actually looking to validate based on the radio selection vs the requirement that *one needs to be* selected; so this does just that.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/wtfdanny/2g0wu5cf/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radios" value="1"> Option 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radios" value="2"> Option 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="validationMsg">Please select something from above</span>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log('Chose radio #', value)
    $('#validationMsg').text('');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are created dynamically after the page load then you need to use this syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#radioButton1" ,function () {
        var isChecked = $("#radioButton1").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked)
            $("#validationMsg").text("");
        else
            $("#validationMsg").text("Please select something from above").css("color", "red");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this, You need to show the message on document.ready event firstly, then hide or remove on selection of radio button, hope it will help.
thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#validationMsg").text("Please select something from above").css("color", "red");
    $("#radioButton1").on("change", function () {
        var isChecked = $("#radioButton1").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked)
            $("#validationMsg").text("");
        else
            $("#validationMsg").text("Please select something from above").css("color", "red");
    });

    $("#radioButton2").change(function () {
        var isChecked = $("#radioButton2").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked)
            $("#validationMsg").text("");
        else
            $("#validationMsg").text("Please select something from above").css("color", "red");
    });
});
```